# having trouble using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, html

This is my first time using reactjs. I installed react and react-dom using npm.

This is my `main.js` file:

```
import React  from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.render(<h1> hello world</h1>,document.getElementById("node"));
```

This is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="node"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Both files are in the same directory, but react isn't changing the VIEW.

Does anyone have any advice for me on how to proceed?

Comment: Is there any console output? How are you including dependencies?

Comment: You also need some kind of build step to compile your JavaScript file containing JSX to code the browser can understand, e.g. Webpack with Babel. If you are just starting out it might be worth looking at a project that is already setup for you, e.g. [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

Comment: @Tholle ill try that thanks

Comment: @Nick they are in a node module. and im importing them in my main.js file

Answer (score -1):

Try running

```
create-react-app APP_NAME
```

Hope this works